# If "dis" makes antonym of a root word, then why doesn't "creet" have a meaning where discreet="dis"+creet?

Tags: morphology, roots

In a dictionary, I found the word "discreet" which means: **not likely to be seen or noticed by many people.**

I think maybe the word discreet is formed by : **"dis"+creet**.
If it is so then what is the meaning of "creet"?
dis is :**no** such as in dislike, disagree and so on.

Comment: Not all words containing an affix can be produced in the modern language (or indeed, in the English of any era) via a productive process yielding a predictable meaning.  When they cannot, we say the combination is *lexicalized*, which means that it's become a single word and needs its own dictionary entry.

Comment: @hjpotter92, Never heard of "con" being used as prefix or suffix. Can you give an example?

Comment: In this case, it's a *lexical word* because the affix was added to it before it was borrowed into English, so it's not possible to produce it via a productive process in English, regardless of whether or not we're talking about the modern language.

Comment: @Mistu4u Ah, I misspoke myself there...

Comment: @Mistu4u - Yes, **congress** – it's the opposite of _progress_. (That's not really true, but some might find it an aptly funny remark during a government shutdown, which is what the U.S. is experiencing as I type this.)

Comment: @J.R., Strange! [Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/congress?q=congress) does not enlist this meaning of congress. But if this meaning is true, the shutdown thing due to US congress's opposition is definitely funny!! :-)

Comment: No, you won't find that in any dictionary. It's a relatively common joke, though, and it tends to get uttered more often when congress isn't getting along.

Answer (score 6):

*Creet* doesn't have a meaning in English. It goes back to its Latin roots.

Discrete came from the Latin [discretus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discretus).

Discretus came from the Latin [discerno](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discerno).

> From dis- (“asunder, in pieces, apart, in two”) + cernō (“see,
>   discern”).

Here's a list of [words derived from cerno](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aEnglish_words_by_Latin_antecedents):

> certain, concern, crime, criminal, decree, discern, discernible,
>   discernment, discreet, discrete, discretion, discretionary,
>   discriminant, discriminate, discrimination, discriminative, excrement,
>   excreta, excrescent, excrete, excretion, excretory, indiscernible,
>   secret, secretary, secretion, secretive, secretory

Answer (score 2):

Your concept is not quite true. Not always "dis" makes an antonym of a word; "dis" can be part of a word itself. [Origin of "discreet"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discreet) as per Merriam-Webster is:

> Middle English, from Anglo-French discret, from Medieval Latin discretus, from Latin, past participle of discernere to separate, distinguish between — more at discern
>   First Known Use: 14th century.

There are a lot of words which does not use "dis" to make a root word antonym. you can consult a dictionary to check them.

Comment: Quite true: _dispose, dispute, discuss, dissuade_ and _distribute_, to name a few.

Comment: On the other hand, a lot of these have origins wherein the "dis-" prefix was some sort of negation, and many of them persist through to the present to one degree or another.  For example "suasion" is a (little-used) synonym of "persuasion", an antonym of which is "dissuasion".  A question that is posed may also be disposed of.  However, to discuss is not necessarily to not cuss.  :)